# javascript reloading page: how to find the culprit

Tags: javascript

I have a page that is being continually reloaded, about every 45 seconds.  If I disable javascript in the browser, the page stops reloading - so I suspect that some javascript is the culprit.  But there's a large amount of it scattered across various .js files, some of them compressed.  So I'm having a hard time poring thru the JS source trying to find the culprit.

I'm looking for ideas on how to find the cause - without reading (and understanding) all of the JS source.

I've tried using Break on Next in Firebug.  It always breaks inside of jquery.min.js - but there's no history in the stack, so I can't tell who called jQuery.

The web page is http://www.sarasotasailingsquadron.org/

Other ideas?

Comment: Easiest would be to link us the webpage so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Body onload, window.onload is the first place to look

Comment: How many js files are we talking? CTRL+F should help a lot assuming you know what you're looking for (there are only so many ways to refresh/reload a page with javascript)

Comment: use firebug to search for `.location`. it's not jquery, most likely you are landing in jquery source because of an anonymous callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I have found part of your problem.  I can't quite find where it originates, but maybe this will help you.

I haven't been able to completely reproduce your issue under Chrome, but every minute or so, I do see a request for your home page.  According to Chrome's developer tools, that request is initiating within jQuery.  (That doesn't mean jQuery is the culprit... that just means that whatever code is making the request is using jQuery to do it.)

In the console, there is a suspicious error message:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.sarasotasailingsquadron.org/".

The call stack drops it down to `$.transition`.  It seems that this has to do with your image transition header, "coin slider".

I've skimmed your code and don't see the reference, but somewhere I suspect you are trying to load your home page as an image in that header.  Maybe you have some invalid HTML or a null URL to the image keeping it from populating the full request URL or something.  In any case, this should help you track down the exact source.

Comment: Many thanks, Brad!  coin_slider.js was the culprit.  I can't explain its behavior, but I do know I was passing bad data to it and resolving that fixed the problem.  Thanks again.